# Kernel recompilation: mp-bios error 8254 timer not connected to ioapic

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

After recompiling my kernel I see this error every time I start linux.
Os starts fine but I see it is not stable at all: sometimes it freezes and I can just reboot it.
I guess it is because of this problem (which does not appear with my already built kernel), what can I do in order to solve it?

Comment: Upgrade your BIOS, or add the `noapic` option to your kernel command line. (What are the messages after that error? It should try a few workarounds and report on whether they worked.)

Comment: I'm not very familiar with kernel recompilation...where to add noapic exactly? And what this option really does?

Comment: Add it to the kernel command line. (How you modify that depends on how you load your kernel. But if you're running your own compiled kernel, you must have configured it to load your kernel. The command line would be set in that same place.) It tells the kernel not to use the [APIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Programmable_Interrupt_Controller), which is a workaround to a bad [DSDT](http://acpi.sourceforge.net/dsdt/index.php). There may be better workarounds, but without knowing your hardware and the exact messages, I can only guess.

Comment: By the way, if you're not familiar with this kind of stuff, compiling your own kernel is not for you. For example, it's hard to imagine you managed to get any of the kernel command line right if you don't know where it is.

Comment: So in the grub I have to open the kernel with cmd line, ok I'll try. Btw it is: I know pc's internal architecture and I set kernel options according to my knoledge. The fact I don't know HOW to recompile (exact commands that is) does not mean I cannot make a kernel suited to my pc.